# What is the origin of __author__?

Tags: python, metadata

Where does the convention of using private metadata variables like `__author__` within a module come from?

[This](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2001-March/013328.html) Python mailinglist thread seems to hint at some discussion about it in 2001, but by the sound of it the convention was already out in the wild.

Other than that, I can only find [this PEP on package metadata](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0345/), which seems influential but tangental at best.

I'd like to try and find some explicit material on the subject so my documentation tool can parse these metadata variables successfully.

Answer (score 22):

My guess is, it's from the old times when packaging meta data was not common then.
In PEP 8 one is encouraged to use the _*version*_ top level variable to hold the revision id of the versioning system in use. This dates back to 2001-05-01. PEP 396 is superseding this for module _*version*_ attributes.

For _*author*_ there is a post from the python dev mailing list, concerning this matter. This one dates back to 2001-03-01. The author questions the use of _*author*_: "What's next ? _*cute_signoff*_ ?".

Since there is no mention in the PEPs, don't worry about _*author*_. Packaging metadata is our friend anyway.

http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2001-March/013328.html

```
Ping just checked in this:

> Log Message:
> Add __author__ and __credits__ variables.
> 
> 
> Index: tokenize.py
> ===================================================================
> RCS file: /cvsroot/python/python/dist/src/Lib/tokenize.py,v
> retrieving revision 1.19
> retrieving revision 1.20
> diff -C2 -r1.19 -r1.20
> *** tokenize.py   2001/03/01 04:27:19 1.19
> --- tokenize.py   2001/03/01 13:56:40 1.20
> ***************
> *** 10,14 ****
>   it produces COMMENT tokens for comments and gives type OP for all operators."""
>   
> ! __version__ = "Ka-Ping Yee, 26 October 1997; patched, GvR 3/30/98"
>   
>   import string, re
> --- 10,15 ----
>   it produces COMMENT tokens for comments and gives type OP for all operators."""
>   
> ! __author__ = 'Ka-Ping Yee '
> ! __credits__ = 'first version, 26 October 1997; patched, GvR 3/30/98'
>   
>   import string, re

I'm slightly uncomfortable with the __credits__ variable inserted
here.  First of all, __credits__ doesn't really describe the
information given.  Second, doesn't this info belong in the CVS
history?  I'm not for including random extracts of a module's history
in the source code -- this is more likely than not to become out of
date.  (E.g. from the CVS log it's not clear why my contribution
deserves a mention while Tim's doesn't -- it looks like Tim probably
spent a lot more time thinking about it than I did.)

Anothor source of discomfort is that there's absolutely no standard
for this kind of meta-data variables.  We've got __version__, and I
believe we once agreed on that (in 1994 or so :-).  But __author__?
__credits__?  What next -- __cute_signoff__?
```

Comment: Given this there is probably no way to reliably parse \_\_author\_\_ or \_\_credits\_\_ attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Those are the earliest uses of the __author__ variable on the python-dev list:

- 2 Mar 2001. Guido van Rossum accepts the usage of the __author__ variable when discussing a Yee Ka-Ping commit from 26 October 1997: https://mail.python.org/archives/list/python-dev@python.org/message/5QQMSB2KYL3XK74LQI44Z4W247FC2O6D/
- 22 Jan 2000, https://mail.python.org/archives/list/python-dev@python.org/message/DVHMRM2RAOVHMSV5XRVMROKD4TTD3J6S/
- 22 Sep 2000, "They are useful for normal modules as well, e.g. __version__, __copyright__, __author__, etc. Looks like its PEP-time again ;-)", https://mail.python.org/archives/list/python-dev@python.org/message/OOEGGDQZYMTTMZRQ2X4ZILJWJRTOUHFK/

btw., the so called "dunder" variables, like __author__ and __version__, were added to PEP8 in 2016, see: https://github.com/python/peps/commit/0aa70aebf102d352b8476f04509a369bf3db276c